# Using $ T_{7} $ of a Taylor series to estimate the value of $ \sin(3^{\circ}) $.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, taylor-expansion, approximation, estimation

This is Part (b) of a problem. Part (a) consisted of finding $ {T_{7}}(x) $ for $ \sin(x) $ at $ a = 0 $, and I got

> $ {T_{7}}(x) = x - x^{3} + x^{5} - x^{7} $.

Now, I need to use $ T_{7} $ to estimate the value of $ \sin(3^{\circ}) $. Do I essentially plug $ 3^{\circ} $ into my answer from Part (a)? I’m confused because my teacher said that $ 3^{\circ} $ must be converted into radians, so if I plug $ 3 $ in, then I’ll have a constant instead of something in radians.

Any help on how to execute this (seemingly easy) problem would be great!

Comment: That's not the right Taylor polynomial, but once you get the right one, you should indeed convert $3^{\circ}$ to radians and plug it into your polynomial.

Comment: your $T_7(x)$ is not correct. you must convert $3$ degrees to $\pi.\frac{3}{180}$ radians.

Comment: Hi Megan. I just edited your post to make it look better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you take derivatives of trig functions line $\sin x$ the argument $(x)$ is assumed to be expressed in radians.  A radian is an angle corresponding to an arc length in a circle that is equal to the radius of that circle; thus since the circumference of the circle is $2\pi r$, $2\pi$ radians is $360^\circ$.

So $3^\circ$ is $3 \times \frac{2\pi}{360} = \frac{\pi}{60}$ radians.

As the comment pointed out, you have the wrong Taylor series (you forgot the $n!$ in the denominator of each term.

Comment: Oops! Thank you so much, this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct Taylor polynomial:
$$
{T_{7}}(x) = x - \frac{x^{3}}{3!} + \frac{x^{5}}{5!} - \frac{x^{7}}{7!}.
$$
Furthermore, for $ n \in \{ 7,8 \} $, we have
$$
\forall x \in \mathbb{R}: \qquad
\sin(x) = {T_{7}}(x) + x^{n} \cdot \epsilon(x),
$$
where $ \epsilon: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ is some function satisfying $ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \epsilon(x) = 0 $. Therefore, $ \sin(3^{\circ}) \approx T_{7} \! \left( \dfrac{3 \pi}{180} \right) $.

Comment: I edited your post to make it look better.

Comment: @BerrickCalebFillmore Ok brother, Thanks a lot.